Casting const of types of std::pair held in std::vector when used to emulate std::map
I am implementing an associative container like std::map. Instead of using a red-black tree, I am using a std::vector. My use case is a data structure that has far more lookups then modifications, but implements the std::map API as close as possible, in order to improve cache performance. This concept is based loosely on EASTL https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL:
template<typename KeyType, typename MappedType>
class vector_map : public std::vector< std::pair< KeyType, MappedType> >
{
public:
    MappedType & operator[]( const KeyType & Key ); // etc.
};

I have encountered an issue when storing std::pair<const KeyType, MappedType> inside the vector, and trying using std::sort() on the inserted data. The const KeyType prevents std::pair from being copyable, which means the sort based on random access container concept fails to compile.
My initial solution (and that taken by EASTL) is to remove the const on KeyType, but that effectively makes it so that the keys can be mutated within the container, which should be a no-no given it is sorted.
One option is to make the underlying vector hidden, and reimplement all of the iterator logic myself, but that requires me to take my vector_map iterator and turn it into a vector iterator for operations like finding. Furthermore, erasing and removing should take a std::vector::iterator, which I want to support as extensions of the std::map.
Is it safe to simply cast all internal iterators from std::vector< std::pair<KeyType, MappedType>>::iterator to std::vector< std::pair<const KeyType, MappedType>>::iterator when working with the public? This would allow me to use the underlying vector iterator (or any underlying container that is random access, such as std::deque) without having to rewrite the iterator.
My gut says sure why not, but I wanted a double check the sanity of my opinion.

That cast itself is not legal as std::vector<T>::iterator and std::vector<U>::iterator are distinct non-related types.

EASTL... I had no idea that Eastman and Laird were so influential in programming circles.

Just for the record: I know you're trying to be compatible with std::map, but notice how std::flat_map's API differs.

@alagner -- yes thanks for the reminder. I can use c++20 but not 23, which is why I am where I am, but perhaps implementing the c++23 interface instead makes more sense.

FWIW I'm pretty sure even std::map stores the keys as non-const, I'm just not sure how they do that.  A look into libc++ or libstdc++ would show how they do it.

@NathanOlver - I have implemented std::map from scratch and looked at many vendor implementations. The keys are const while the pointers in the nodes are not. Shuffling a tree of nodes mutates the pointers. In a vector, shuffling the ordered data requires swapping the types via copy, which is where my const issue trips me up.

@Steven You're right.  Looks like per this the implementation is allowed to use "magic" to get this type of behavior.

@alagner interesting enough the boost std_ext implementation of std::flat_set allows the elements to be mutated such that they are out of order. This may be an oversight of the sample implementation, or a requirement to allow copies.

@Steven It is possible to modify the key of a std::flat_set, but semantically it is prohibited by https://eel.is/c++draft/associative.reqmts#general-3.sentence-4 if it would affect the ordering. The standard basically chose the approach to make the key non-const, but forbid the user to modify (at least in such a way that the ordering is affected). const keys in the interface without UB in the implementation and with the legacy iterator concepts is not possible as far as I can tell efficiently. The C++20 ranges iterator concepts are more general and would permit it.

C++23 provides std::flat_map for that purpose. The set and unordered alternatives also have the flat variation available now. If you can't use C++23, the reference implementation of these containers is available in boost libraries. Don't reinvent the will.

@Red.Wave I am bound to our own internal implementations for a variety of reasons so I can't simply use boost. But thank you for the suggestion.

@Steven boost is open source; that means you can just copy the parts you need. The only restriction is license policy. Other reasons are negotiable. If the tool chain is also fixed at old version, then you can at least ge some insights into your own implementation. My prime suggestion is upgrade to C++23; that's the smart way.

@Red.Wave The development environment I work in is restrictive and slow to move. We are only now working with C++20. In my private world I am be on c++23 and exploit all open source code!

You don't have to use either boost or C++23. Take a look at at std::flat_map doc. It doesn't impose the constness of key on value_type. The implementation is also a bit different from yours. By mimicing the existing std, you can maximize forward compatibility; a future move to newer std won't cost much. Just check it out.
